# RHEL 8 - yum commands started throwing a 470 error

Tags: yum, jenkins, rhel8

I am using RHEL 8 on a Jenkins agent and have been trying to install the required dependencies using yum. After some trial and error, I started receiving the following error on

`yum update -y`

> Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'remi-safe': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Status code: 470

Below is the full output

```
+ sudo yum update -y
```

> Updating Subscription Management repositories.
> Unable to read consumer identity
> Subscription Manager is operating in container mode.
>
> This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
>
> Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64   15 MB/s |  16 MB     00:01    
> Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 480  B/s |  70  B     00:00    
> Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'remi-safe':\
>
> - Status code: 470 for http://cdn.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/safe/mirror (IP: 109.238.14.107)\
> - Status code: 470 for http://cdn.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/safe/mirror (IP: 176.31.103.194)
>   Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'remi-safe': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Status code: 470 for http://cdn.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/safe/mirror (IP: 176.31.103.194)

Status code 470 seems like a pretty obscure error code and I cannot find anything relevant to this error on the internet.

Comment: 470 http error is unassigned, (https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) so you can use it for anything you want. I've seen some people are using it as 'redemption failed' to indicate the access codes for this customer are depleted (https://support.vitalsource.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404193867799-470-Error-Redemption-failed), but you indicate you use rhel 8 and the mirror is for rhel 7, so maybe your repo definition is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, but cannot reproduce, never see this error.

Answer (score 1):

This line gives a clue:

```
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
```

RHEL requires active subscription to access repositories. Even a free (as in beer) version. Do you have one? The free subscription must be renewed every year, did you forget to do so?

Comment: I don't have one but can get one ordered. However, it was working before and suddenly stopped. Is there a free tier to it?

Comment: Yes, there is a free tier. And as mentioned - it might have just expired. Look at RedHat website how to register yourself and the system. Please note that free tier might have some licensing restrictions and you should evaluate if it is appropriate for your purpose.

Comment: Fair enough. I just want to get the system working before asking my employer for a license

Comment: @saq7, free license is available only for developers. Production usage of free RH is forbidden and you should buy/get license to be able to update the software.